# Cannot log in to SSRS 2012 using any account

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssrs, ssrs-2012

I have installed SQL Sever 2012 along with Reporting Services.

I have configured Reporting Services using the Reporting Services Configuration Manager. It seems like the service is running properly, however I am unable to log in to it using any account.

I have tried using :

- the built-in Administrator account, added to the sysadmin role in SQL Server.
- another account, the one that was used to install SQL Server, also a sysadmin and a member of the Administrators group.

I have tried both logging in to the Report Manager in IE (also tried to run IE as Administrator as sometimes suggested) and via SSMS.

I am trying to log in locally.

I can tell that the service is running because when I try to log in to the Report Manager, I seen the following error in the familiar web interface:

```
The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.
```

**Edit:**

Added screenshots are requested

[image: Connection]

The connection goes through without a problem

[image: Server Details]

[image: Report Manager]

As you can see I have changed the default port. I started with 80 but it wasn't working and site I already have IIS serving websites on port 80 I thought it was safer to use another port.

[image: Advanced Settings]

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?

Comment: I am using IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Web Edition.

Comment: SSRS doesn't use IIS.  Can you post some screenshots of the SSRS configuration manager?

Comment: I have added the screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't figure out what was wrong with the installation. I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling under the Administrator account, and then I could log in to SSRS as Administrator.